# How to write this UPDATE in MSQL, to update multiple rows with different WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have to code this logic:

```
UPDATE imported 
   SET col1 = 'first' 
 WHERE col2 = 'value one',
   SET col1 = 'second' 
 WHERE col2 = 'value two';
```

There are going to be multiple updates in one query, so I don't want to stuff the server by doing update separately for each row

Also: if 2 conditions can be combined, like Where col2='this' AND col3='that'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added an example of multiple conditions in a `CASE` statement.

```
UPDATE imported
SET col1 = CASE
              WHEN col2 = 'value one' THEN 'first'
              WHEN col2 = 'value two' THEN 'second'
              WHEN col2 = 'other val' AND col3 = 'condition' THEN 'third value'
           END
WHERE col2 IN ('value one', 'value two')
   OR (col2 = 'other val' AND col3 = 'condition')
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, except that it should be END instead of END CASE

however, how can I add another condition to WHERE in it for col3 to be something too ?

Comment: I have updated my answer for you to see the col3 where condition.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
update imported
set col1 = case col2
           when 'value one' then 'first'
           when 'value two' then 'second'
           end
where col2 = 'value one'
   or col2 = 'value two'
```

Or you could just use two UPDATEs:

```
update imported set col1 = 'first'  where col2 = 'value one';
update imported set col1 = 'second' where col2 = 'value two';
```

Comment: thanks, got it working with Adams answer, but yours seems to be workable too

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would use two statements, but here's how to do it in one statement:

```
UPDATE imported 
   SET col1 = if(col2 = 'value one', 'first', 'second') 
 WHERE col2 in ('value one', 'value two');
```

Your question states exactly two options, so I've used the brief `if` statement. If you have other conditions, better use a case:

```
UPDATE imported 
   SET col1 = case col2 
       when 'value one' then 'first'
       when 'value two' then 'second'
       when 'value three' then 'third'
       else 'something else' end 
 WHERE col2 in ('value one', 'value two', 'value three');
```